# How can I extract right-to-left text from .doc and .docx files using Apache POI in java?

Tags: java, apache-poi, right-to-left

I’m developing an application that will take .doc or .docx files as input and extract their words to a database table.

I tried Apache POI for this purpose and I successfully managed this with documents with left-to-right text format (e.g., English).

Here is the code:

```
// FilterDOC Method Which Tacke A Document As Input and Return A Generic 
// List Withs Its Words

public static void parseDoc(File SelectedFile, FileReader in) {
try {
         // Create a POI File System object 
        POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(
                SelectedFile));

     // Create a document for this file 
    HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);

     // Create a WordExtractor to read the text of the word document
            WordExtractor we = new WordExtractor(doc);

        String ExtractedText = we.getText();

     // Removing New Empty Lines
    String RemoveEmptyLines = ExtractedText.replaceAll("[\n\r]", "");

     // Filtering document of any symbols
    String[] Wordlist = RemoveEmptyLines
                .split("[:\\,\\.\\}\\?\\{\\[\\]\\‘\\_\\*\\&\\%\\#\\$\\@\\!\\~\\/\\//\\|\\?\\“\\:-\\;\\W\\s+]");

    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (String line : Wordlist) {

            if (line != null && !line.trim().isEmpty()
                    && !line.equals("\\W\\s+")) {
                lines.add(line.trim());

            }

        }

       // output the document
    for (String string : lines) {

            System.out.println(string);}
                  in.close();



    } 

          catch (IOException e){ 
            System.out.println("IO Exception !!"+ e.getMessage());      }
}
```

How can I use the same library with documents with right-to-left text format (e.g., Arabic)?

Comment: Could you clarify what the problem is you're seeing? No text? Incorrect characters? Wrong direction?

Answer (score 0):

For right-to-let set:

```
sheet.setRightToLeft()
```